# Python3 apple mobileconfig download server

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, udid, apple-profile-manager

I am trying to build a system to get ios udid like https://get.udid.io site.
In the process of creating the system, we are creating a server that provides mobileconfig.
There is a problem making python3 and Azure function.
As per Apple's guide, I added 'application/x-apple-appen-config' to the header and include the signed mobileconfig file in the body to deliver the response.
The file is received but it is 0byte.

If I print it using readlines in the middle, I think I can read the file properly, so what's the problem?

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    f = open("signed.mobileconfig", 'rb')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
    data = f.read()
    f.close()

    header = {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-apple-aspen-config'}
    return func.HttpResponse(data, status_code=200, headers=header)
```